# Pass custom css_class to deform Button

Tags: pyramid, deform, colander

I have a basic form and schema..

```
class NewSchema(colander.MappingSchema):
        name = colander.SchemaNode(colander.String(),
            widget=text_input)

schema = NewSchema()
myform = Form(schema, buttons=('submit'))
```

Now this works fine, however I want to pass a custom css class to the submit button, I would expect todo:

```
schema = PaymentSchema()
myform = Form(schema, buttons=('submit', css_class="someclass"))
```

But this doesn't work, how can I pass this class attribute to a button like this?

EDIT: I have also tried:

```
butt = deform_form.Button(name='submita', css_class="test")
schema = PaymentSchema()
myform = Form(schema, buttons=(butt,))
```

Which renders the html

```
<div class="actions">

    <button
        id="deformsubmita"
        name="submita"
        type="submit"
        class="btn btnText submit primaryAction"
        value="submita"

        >
    <span>Submita</span>
    </button>

</div>
```

Comment: which version of deform you are using?

Answer (score 2):

Your first code example will not work, the second is on the right track, but may have a typo in deform button class name. Compare yours to mine. You almost got it, keep on trying.

According to [API docs](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/deform/en/latest/api.html#module-deform) either pass a sequence of strings or a sequence of button objects.

> buttons
>
> A sequence of strings or deform.form.Button objects
>   representing submit buttons that will be placed at the bottom of the
>   form. If any string is passed in the sequence, it is converted to
>   deform.form.Button objects.

Therefore I create a single button with applied CSS class and pass it in a tuple to parameter `buttons` while creating the form. This example is using [deform2.0a2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/deform/2.0a2)

```py
class WikiViews(object):
    def __init__(self, request):
        self.request = request

    @property
    def wiki_form(self):
        schema = WikiPage()
        submit = deform.Button(name='submit', css_class='red')
        return deform.Form(schema, buttons=(submit,))

    @view_config(route_name='wikipage_add',
             renderer='deform2_demo:templates/wikipage_addedit.pt')
    def wikipage_add(self):
        form = self.wiki_form.render()
        ...
```

deform renders this to HTML:

```html
    <form id="deform" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8" class="deform">

      <fieldset class="deformFormFieldset">   

        <input type="hidden" name="_charset_">
        <input type="hidden" name="__formid__" value="deform">

         <div class="form-group  item-title" title="" id="item-deformField1">    
           <label for="deformField1" class="control-label required" id="req-deformField1">Title</label>    
           <input type="text" name="title" value="" id="deformField1" class=" form-control ">

         </div>

         <!-- removed HTML for more deform fields -->

         <div class="form-group">
           <button id="deformsubmit" name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary red" value="submit">Submit</button>

         </div>
      </fieldset>

    </form>
```